# Magento - $product->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku) not working

Tags: product, model

I'm running into an interesting problem....

When trying to load products using `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);` it returns `false`.

Using `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);` works.

I've checked and confirmed the following:

- Sku exists (var_dumped it and used it in admin search grid and product comes up)
- Tried `getSkuById` from both the model and resource model and it returns `false`

What can be next steps

**EDIT**

Using the resource model **does not work** - this was the solution to the 'possible duplicate' question.

This seems to be a APC caching issue since on my local environment the code works just fine.

What steps can I take to 'hole punch' apc for this script? (or does that not make sense)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure in what context you are using it.

`loadByAttribute()` method uses collection and filter by the attribute set:

```
/**
 * Load entity by attribute
 *
 * @param Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Interface|integer|string|array $attribute
 * @param null|string|array $value
 * @param string $additionalAttributes
 * @return bool|Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract
 */
public function loadByAttribute($attribute, $value, $additionalAttributes = '*')
{
    $collection = $this->getResourceCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect($additionalAttributes)
        ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value)
        ->setPage(1,1);

    foreach ($collection as $object) {
        return $object;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So sometimes observers for product loading don't apply and you won't get all the required data set.

To be in safe side, it's better to load the product as:

```
if ($productId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getIdBySku($sku)) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
}
```

Comment: it seems that the difference between my local environment and the server is that the server has apc cache enabled. running the command you shared is still not breaking through the cache for some reason

Answer (score 2):

usually, this should work.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
```

> please print_r($sku);

you should debug and get $sku value.

if sku is not defined in backend than specify.

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 2):

In addition of @MagePsycho,

***`loadByAttribute()`*** basically loads the product collection and  filter those collection by sku and then it is returns the collection first item.

That *`particular sku`* does not give result ***because of*** `that particular' does not exits at products collection` and  that `product have calling from a collection`.

```
$collection = $this->getResourceCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect($additionalAttributes)
    ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value)
    ->setPage(1,1);
```

As per magento, *** a product does not visible at collection because of Product's**     [flat setting enable](http://inchoo.net/magento/flat-tables-in-magento-and-product-collection/) and  **due to  some reason like  magento condition like  visibility, stock, website,store*** ,a product not include at product flat collection.

As `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);` code is **direct call of product  model** then it ***give result and it does not call collection,just call a particular model by id*** ,So you get result